# while loop for retrieving data

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to retrieve multiple cars from a car rental database based on the model, so if someone clicks on Ford it would retrieve all cars that have a Model ID of 2 for example. The current code I have only shows the first record in the database, how do I make a while loop that would echo the rows for each match?

```
$ModelID = $_GET['model_id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT RegNumber, Colour FROM Car WHERE ModelID = '$ModelID'");   

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row["RegNumber"];
echo $row["Colour"];
```

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ echo $row["RegNumber"];}`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['RegNumber'];
    echo $row['Colour'];
}
```

For more details, please go through the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). And never forget to escape data inside the query, in that case you should use [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function

```
$escapedModelId = $mysqli->real_escape_string($ModelID);
$query= "SELECT RegNumber, Colour FROM Car WHERE ModelID = '$escapedModelId'"; 
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["RegNumber"];
        echo $row["Colour"];  
    }
}
```